# Firing Triggers contains a matches RegEx that I didn't set

Tags: google-tag-manager

I'm trying to setup an event that tracks outbound clicks from my site, that don't contain my URL.

I've setup an event and trigger, everything fires except one trigger that I haven't set.

`_triggers` matches RegEx `(^$|((^|,)11045625_7($|,)))`

Here's what it looks like when I click a link that **should** fire the event:

[image: GTM Preview]

I've followed a guide [here](https://netvantagemarketing.com/blog/tracking-website-exits-using-google-tag-manager/) that details the process, however it hasn't worked for me.

Comment: You need to upload the image in your question.

Comment: @l'L'l oops thanks for pointing it out - uploaded

Answer (score 0):

From your image and the article you linked to, seems you have *Click Text* does not contain your URL.com rather than *Click URL* does not contain your URL.com (as per the article instructions)